# Including header contents from a External URL into a JSP file

Tags: html, jsp, header, external-url

There is a header content which comes from a external url(say `http://sample.com/header.html`). I want to include this header in my jsp file that actually I can see this header in my jsp page. When I run my jsp page this header url should be shown on the top of my jsp page.

I appreciate if you can help me with that!

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    </head>
        <body>
            <c:import url="https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl"  /> 
         </body>

</html>
```

Comment: We can't see any URL. Can you edit your post?

Comment: I did not add a specific url. I mean a link which clicking on that, opens a header content. Could be any header.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) taglib in your path,

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

To import content from an external URL to a JSP, JSTL provides tag.

For instance,

```
 <c:import url="http://external.com/some/fragment.html" />
```

will add the content from the url specified to JSP at the request time. See the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981075/include-external-website-inside-div-in-jsp#6983802) 
From [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)

**update:**
You can try with `<iframe>` if you looking for embedding `google` page in your header (as if required by you). See the code sample below,

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" style="width: 90%; height: 300px"
scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0">
</iframe>
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: but it does not bring the css...right? I want to read the complete css

Comment: It's not like that, you can the valid URL whatever it is. Try and let me know.

Comment: I added a simple jsp code in my original question that contains your code...you can try it and see the css does not come through

Comment: Please let me know if you know what the issue is. Thanks!

Comment: No, I do not see any error. Did you try the code that I added to see what I mean?

Comment: If it returns a complete `<html>` document and/or is context-dependent, then you really have to use `<iframe>`

Comment: iframe is not really what I want. I have used cfinclude in coldfusion code and include in PHP to use a url as the header of my pages and another url as the footer of my pages. I am trying to do the same thing in JSP but include does not work like it does in coldfusion and PHP. That's why I used import, but still I have problem including that url as my header/footer in my JSP page.

Comment: The `<c:import>` works on external URLs (thus, resources in a completely different webapp, but those have to be publicly accessible; i.e. you have got to see the desired include content already when copy-pasting the URL in browser's address bar). See [Details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162111/how-to-load-html-page-which-is-outside-application-context-using-jsp-include-or#19184605)

Comment: I have tested the code in my original question with a publicly accessible url as the header/footer instead of using google url (which I cannot share here) but It does not work...If you try the code in my original question with a publicly shared url, you see what I mean. Thanks!